# ARP & layer 3 switch

Tags: networking, forwarding, arp

The following is based on my understanding of network, if there's anything wrong, please point it out.

Considering the following scenario. A host (sender) is to send a IP packet:

1. sender fills in the destination IP address
2. sender fills in the destination MAC address (may use ARP)
3. switch forwards the packet based on the MAC address.

Here's my question:

Can we get rid of ARP, if we are using a layer 3 switch? because a layer 3 switch forwarding the packets based on IP address.

Comment: @YuHao Please don't resurrect blatantly off-topic questions from tow and a half years ago to fix the formatting. Just vote to close. There's no point improving the formatting (it can't be migrated).

Comment: @AndrewMedico I did the edit **after** voting to close this question. It's off-topic, but it's already here, improving its format does no harm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switches don't really use ARP in the meaning they don't send out out ARPs but they do utilise their functions when a pc sends out an arp.

Switches with IP interfaces's use ARP in the same way any other device uses ARP to communicate. This can be on a L2 switch as the management interface, or a layer 3 switch with IP VLAN interfaces.

An ARP is broadcasted, and so switches do flood it out all ports. Once the device which the ARP is intended to reach see's the ARP, it replies directly to the device which sent the ARP with it's MAC address. The original device then sends the traffic (which caused it to send an ARP) directly to the MAC of the responder. It's at this point the switch uses it's MAC table to forward the frames out the correct port.

source [techexams.](http://www.techexams.net/forums/ccna-ccent/67346-switches-do-they-use-arp.html)

Answer (score 0):

You still need ARP. A layer-3 switch is basically a laer-3 router and a layer-2 switch combination. The layer-3 switch is a layer-2 switch for the purposes of forwarding traffic on the same layer-2 domain, but a layer-3 router for traffic destined for a different subnet.

Any host-to-host (a router is just a host, too) traffic still needs layer-2 to first deliver it, and that requires a layer-2 address to forward it to the destination (another host on the same layer-2 domain, including a router if the IP address is not in the same subnet). ARP gets a layer-2 address based on a layer-3 address, so it is still necessary.